# Does reloadData of Tableview execute immediately in this case

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I read that `[_tableView reloadData]` sends a  message to the main queue to update and display the data in the Table View. Based on this I would like to discuss the following case. Suppose another method sends a message to the main queue before `[_tableView reloadData]` in that case will the second message get processed before `[_tableView reloadData]` ?

Now this is my case

Suppose I have two threads `TA` and `TB` and I have two methods `MethodA`and `MethodB` which look like this

This is `MethodA`

```
- (void) MethodA
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [Myarray addObject:@"SomeObject"];
                    ///----------<TimeFrameA>----------------
                    [_tableView reloadData]
                });
}
```

This is `MethodB`

```
- (void) MethodB
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    //Runs under the assumption the "SomeObject" has already been displayed in Tableview
                    //Make changes to TableView/
                });
}
```

Suppose that `MethodB` is called by `ThreadB` and occurs during `TimeFRameA`.
in that case will MethodB be called before  `[_tableView reloadData]` ?
Is there any way for me to make sure that the `MethodB` only runs when the tableView is displaying the updated data ?

Comment: Method B could be actually called during TimeFrameA, but the async task of Method B will not run until after your call to reloadData has returned. However as some of the reloadData actions themselves are scheduled your MethodB task could easily run before the table reload has started or fully completed. Your main issue might be knowing when reloadData has actually finished to know when it is safe to execute Method B. Why not queue a code block into an array: then have a timer on the main thread which flushes that array of blocks when it knows its safe. So dispatch to a dispatch queue.

Comment: The problem here is MethodA and MethodB are both being called by a delegate.The only thing for sure is that MethodA is called before MethodB. MethodB could be called almost in parallel with MethodA and sometimes after a second or Two. If I use you approach after the table has been updated i wouldnt know when to call methodB . it might need to call it instantly or not for a couple of seconds. I wouldnt know.

Comment: I was suggesting you run Method B immediately. However instead of dispatching the existing code to run which might run too early, dispatch code which adds the original code as a block into a queue with some tag for the object you expect to be rendered in the table. Then start a timer on the main queue whose job it is to flush these pending blocks: the timer looks at the head of the queue, checks the table and if the item is there executes the block. You kill the timer when the queue is flushed.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. However I believe there has to be a simpler way of making sure the table updates instantly

Comment: In A, you would be better to not reloadData and instead insert a new row or update just the affected row. Really you should be updating the data model from both threads and calling reload for the affected rows from both threads. iOS should then take care of splicing the updates together. You have no guarantee that the row for the data being adjusted is on screen even if it knows about "SomeObject".

Comment: I will definitely try this suggestion. I wont call `reloadData` from the blocks instead ill call them from the non-ui threads.

Answer (score 2):

The main dispatch queue (which is associated with the main thread)
is a *serial* queue, not concurrent. Therefore it cannot happen
that in

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [Myarray addObject:@"SomeObject"];
                    ///----------<TimeFrameA>----------------
                    [_tableView reloadData]
                });
}
```

any other code executes on the main queue between adding the object
and reloading the table view.

Any other block dispatched to the main queue executes either before
or after this block.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use "dispatch_group" to synchronize.

Create a dispatch group object by calling:

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();
```

In MethodA use:

```
-(void) MethodA {
    dispatch_group_enter(group);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [Myarray addObject:@"SomeObject"];
                    ///----------<TimeFrameA>----------------
                    [_tableView reloadData];
                    dispatch_group_leave();
                });
}
```

In MethodB wait for the `group` to complete and then perform further operations:

```
-(void) MethodB {
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Runs under the assumption the "SomeObject" has already been displayed in Tableview
        //Make changes to TableView/
    });
}
```